# Spark Group By on large data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to switch to Spark from pig.For our use case, we generate json documents from relational database to store and search using elastic search. This requires lots of joining and grouping. I am wondering if there is Pig Group By and JSONStorage equivalent in Spark. There is GroupByKey but what I read is not recommended. 
Example..

1. `A = load 'student' AS (name:chararray,age:int,gpa:float);`
       `DESCRIBE A; A: {name: chararray,age: int,gpa: float}`

   ```
   DUMP A; (John,18,4.0F) (Mary,19,3.8F) (Bill,20,3.9F) (Joe,18,3.8F)

   B = GROUP A BY age;

   Result:  (18,{(John,18,4.0F),(Joe,18,3.8F)}) (19,{(Mary,19,3.8F)})
   (20,{(Bill,20,3.9F)})
   ```

Does anyone have any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with the grouped data? `groupByKey` is not recommended mostly when it can be replaced by the more efficient `reduceByKey`, which might be applicable, depending on the way the grouped data will be used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zohar. I am creating multilevel document to store in Elastic Search. For example, if a person has two address and phone numbers, I want to group the data by person and create one document with personId as parent element and his address Information as an array.

Comment: Then I don't think there's an alternative to using `groupByKey`. As long as there's no single group that would be too large, performance should be reasonable (comparable to Pig).